# AngularJS + RoR: call controller's function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to call function from AngularJS controller in my HTML template. My HTML (Slim) code looks like that:

```
- if !flash.empty?
  p true
  | {{ onLoginClicked() }}
```

When `if` statement is true I need to call function `onLoginClicked()` while page is loading (when login error occurs), so only once per refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ng-click directive to call this function in html

```
ng-click="onLoginClicked()"
```

and for If condition also u can use ng-if instead of normal if in html

ng-if ="true"

Comment: My `if` condition works fine, problem is within calling function. Unfortunately, ng-click doesn't work for me.

Comment: U have to use ng-app,ng-controller and then only call ng-click. Then only it works..

Comment: Whole code is in ng-app and ng-controller which has function I need to call.